# Trying to create a FA2 token with Archetype

Tags: fa2, archetype

I’m trying to create a FA2 token, for this I use https://github.com/completium/archetype-fa2/blob/main/contracts/fa2_fungible.arl as an example. When I change line 71 to put my ipfs link in bytes (0x697066733a2f2f516d534b764e6272444a4a754d5a4a56735367456d386d435651655a797658445443506459344e743745384e4765) the metadata doesn’t update on tzkt.io but if I don’t change the line the medata updates.

Could someone explain why?
From Slack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try with this structure of json :

```
{
  "symbol": "MC",
  "name": "My Coin",
  "decimals": 6,
  "description": "An example of My Coin",
  "artifactUri": "ipfs://QmPibs6dkHjoJAkE9BiPURCnCBfphaT7P6y5MZ4eTYtyS9",
  "displayUri": "ipfs://QmPibs6dkHjoJAkE9BiPURCnCBfphaT7P6y5MZ4eTYtyS9",
  "thumbnailUri": "ipfs://QmPibs6dkHjoJAkE9BiPURCnCBfphaT7P6y5MZ4eTYtyS9",
  "isTransferable": true,
  "isBooleanAmount": false,
  "shouldPreferSymbol": false
}
```

and replace values by your owns, do you still have issue ?